# Group method not recognized in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

LINQ-newb having trouble using grouping.  I'm trying to query an IEnumerable called dosesWithHighestScore.

I'm following this example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336747.aspx#minGrouped

Here's my code:

```
    var doseWithLowestVolumeForForm =
        from d in dosesWithHighestScore
        group d by d.formulation.form into g                
        select new { 
            Form = g.Key, 
            LowDose = g.Group.Min(d => d.doseAdministrableAmount)
        };
```

The use of "Group" is causing this error:

'System.Linq.IGrouping' does not contain a definition for 'Group' and no extension method 'Group' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IGrouping' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here are my usings:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You an get rid of the `Group` term in your assignment to `LowDose`. In LINQ-to-objects, a group is itself an `IEnumerable<>`, so you can apply other LINQ operations to it without any additional qualifiers. The `Key` property is provided on `IGrouping` so that you can access the value by which the group was ... well, grouped.

```
var doseWithLowestVolumeForForm =
        from d in dosesWithHighestScore
        group d by d.formulation.form into g                
        select new { 
            Form = g.Key, 
            LowDose = g.Min(d => d.doseAdministrableAmount)
        };
```

The examples on the site that show the use of a `Group` property are incorrect.

Comment: That compiles - thanks!  So, one more follow-up question: how do I access the results?  I thought I would be able to do something like dosesWithLowestVolumeForForm[0].Form but that's not working.

Comment: The result of a LINQ statement is a query object ... not an array. There are different ways of accessing the results - depending on what you want to do with them. A common way is to use a `foreach` loop to evaluate each result; as in: `foreach( var item in doseWithLowestVolumeForForm ) { ... }`. Alternatively, if you are only interested in the first result, you can do: `doseWithLowestVolumeForForm.First()` which will return the first result in the query. Other alternatives exist too... but, again, it depends on what you need to do with the results.